# How to pass array that need to fill up by C++ code ?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I work with some 3rd party dll. 
This 3rd party dll is C++ code and one of his method signature need to have array and fill up this array with the right values.

its look like this

```
 struct Val
 {
       public int v1;
       public int v2;
 }

 UpdateValues(Val[] arrayToUpdate, int length);
```

So, the 3rd party dll is getting the array ( not empty array ) and update the values of each item of this array.

I don't know how to define this method signature on c# code.

( i doing it by using PInvoke )

Comment: You need to know the return value, and then there is nothing else.. you use PInvoke and thats it

Comment: Indeed. You start off by knowing the C++ signature, and how it is meant to be called, which you have not yet presented.

Answer (score 0):

One way to implement this is to create a middle layer library on C++/CLI (Managed C++) which will work with Native C++ library calls itself, but also provide C# managed API for your C# application. So, on a top level it will work like this:

```
    Your C# app    <->    C++/CLI middle lib     <-> C++ native lib
```

You can find an example of a such calls in my open source project https://bitbucket.org/optiklab/roboball which works like this:

```
    FootballRobot C# app    <->   RobotMoveLib C++/CLI   <->   MoviRadioUM C++
```

So, an example of passing array of Char's from C# to C++ looks like this:
1. C++/CLI method gets array as a parameter:

```
    void CMoviRadioUM::Movi_radio_send_message(..., array<Byte> ^ msg)
    {
       // Convert to native format
       pin_ptr<Byte> data = &msg[0];
       unsigned char * pData = data;

       // Native call to C++ lib passes Char *
       movi_radio_send_message(..., &pData);
    }
```

2. And from C# we can call it like this:

   ```
   _moviRadio = new CMoviRadioUM();
   _moviRadio.Movi_radio_send_message(..., Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
   ```

To pass an array of more complex structures, like struct or class I believe you will need to convert it into arrays of simple object or pointers, because Native C++ library will know nothing about your Manager

Comment: Passing an array is easy with pinvoke. Why resort to an extra assembly?